# Delete jenkins jobs having the matching pattern

Tags: jenkins, jobs

How to delete jobs on jenkins having the prefix "Data_jobs_" ?
and 
How to disable all jobs having prefix "Data_jobs_server" ?

Anyone know how to do this by going /script page ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```groovy
for (job in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getProjects()) {
    if (job.name.startsWith("Data_jobs_"))  {
        job.delete()
    }
    else if (job.name.startsWith("Data_jobs_server"))  {
        job.disable()
    }
}
```

Comment: The if/else is the wrong way around. `Data_jobs_server` will never be disabled, because it gets **deleted**!

Comment: To be sure to get jobs in subfolders use for (job in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class))

Comment: I am the admin but getting error "hudson.security.AccessDeniedException3: nageswar.k. is missing the Job/Delete permission